# Javascript add double quote around company name using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a row of data that I would like to add double quote around the company name ("Test1, Inc")

original: `12345, 67890, Name \"The Name\", More Name, 99999, Test1, Inc, 2017-01-01 00:00:00`

expected: `12345, 67890, Name \"The Name\", More Name, 99999, "Test1, Inc", 2017-01-01 00:00:00`

I wasn't able to get it exactly rignt. Anybody expert to regex knows why?

```
let a = "12345, 67890, Name \"The Name\", More Name, 205298, Test1, Inc, 2017-01-01 00:00:00";
a= a.replace(/(,)(.*,.*Inc)(,)/g, `${'$1'}\"${'$2'}\"${'$3'}`)
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing in your regular expression that prevents `.*` from including other commas. So the first `(,)` matches the first comma in the string, `(.*,.*Inc)` matches everything up to the last `Inc`, and the second `(,)` matches the comma after that.

Change it to `[^,]*` so it will only match a name that doesn't include another comma.

There's also no need to use a template string for the replacement. `$1`, `$2`, etc. are not variables, they're implemented by the `replace()` method.

And if you don't want to include the space in the company name, you should include `\s*` in the first capture group.

```js
let a = "12345, 67890, Name \"The Name\", More Name, 205298, Test1, Inc, 2017-01-01 00:00:00";
a= a.replace(/(,\s*)([^,]*,[^,]*Inc)(,)/g, '$1"$2"$3')
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `/([^, ]+,[^,]*Inc)/g`; Here use `[^,]` to match non comma characters:

```js
let a = "12345, 67890, Name \"The Name\", More Name, 205298, Test1, Inc, 2017-01-01 00:00:00";
a= a.replace(/([^, ]+,[^,]*Inc)/g, '"$1"')
console.log(a);
```